# find first string starting with vowel in LIST Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am brand new to python -

I have to build a function called `'first__vowel'`.  ACCEPT a list of strings as input
and RETURN the first string that starts with a lowercase vowel `("a","e","i","o", or "u")`. if no string starts with vowel, RETURN the empty string `("")`.

Can you help build this function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
def first_vowel(lst):
    # iterate over list using for loop
    for i in lst:
        # check if first letter is vowel
        if i and i[0] in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
            return i 
    return ""

k = ['sad','dad','mad','asd','eas']
print(first_vowel(k))
```

Or You can also use `regex`

```
import re

def first_vow(lst):
    pat = re.compile(r'^[aeiou][a-zA-Z]*')
    for i in lst:
        match = re.match(pat, lst)
        if match:
            return i
    return ""

k = ['sad','Aad','mad','','asd','eas']
first_vow(k)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

def first_vowel(ss):
    for s in ss:
        if s and s[0] in vowels:
            return s
    return ""
```

Test:

```
first_vowel(["Drere", "fdff", "", "aBD", "eDFF"])
'aBD'
```

Comment: this is working. thank you. What does s[0] mean with "and" in the syntax?

Comment: @FHamad `if s` means if the string is not empty; `and` simply AND; `s[0]` is the first character in the string. I recommend you to take a simple python course, e.g., at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm

Comment: @FHamad If this helps please consider to mark this answer as accepted (if you don't mind). Thanks!

Comment: i used this answer. is there a way to mark accepted? please let me know how, new to this site.

Comment: @FHamad There is V mark right under `<up> 3 <down>` next to my answer. Please click on the V mark and it will turn green like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png

Comment: Yours is good as well- Given my level of expertise (barely none) , i went for the other one. Thanks for sharing yours. Its really helping me learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `str.startswith()` function too:

```
def first_vowel(lst):
    for elem in lst:
        if elem.startswith(('a','e','i','o','u')):
            return elem
    return ''
k = ['', 'b','sad','dad','mad','asd','eas']
print(first_vowel(k))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = ['hi', 'there', 'its', 'an' , 'answer', '']

def first_vowel(var):
    for i in var:
        if i.startswith(('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')): return i


first_vowel(l1) # output-> 'its'
```